# ? symbol in url in symfony2

Tags: symfony, url

In my project i want a normal standard get URL like `www.myproject.com?search=asd`.But in symfony2 questionmark("?") giving error showing URL not found (404 error).

I'm able to access `www.myproject.com/search=asd`. Is there any specific setting in config file so that questionmark("?") is allowed in URL? and In my project I'm using annotations and I have many such URL's which need questionmark("?") in URL.So i need general setting if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony doesn't prevent you from using question marks in paths.

Are you sure you don't need the slash in `www.myproject.com?search=asd` so that it looks like `www.myproject.com/?search=asd`? If you are still getting the `404` status, then there is no route for the root path `/`.